# "sqlite3: Error: too many options: "INTO" " in android application

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android application I am trying to use following line of code:

```
Process runJob = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.launcher/databases/launcher.db \"INSERT INTO favorites VALUES(100,'someText');\"");
```

but it doesn't work. In stderr there is a message

```
03-12 13:41:44.841: I/some(3084): stderr = sqlite3: Error: too many options: "INTO"
03-12 13:41:44.841: I/some(3084): stderr = Use -help for a list of options.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: How many attributes does the table `favorites` contains?

Comment: How many columns are in the table: favorites?

Comment: show me your CREATE TABLE query

Comment: Try adding the columns: INSERT INTO favorites(<col_1>, <col_2>) VALUES(100,'someText')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec(String)` splits the input on spaces and does not honor the `"` quotes like a shell would do.

Use `exec(String[])` instead:

```
...exec(new String[] {
    "sqlite3",
    "/data/data/com.android.launcher/databases/launcher.db",
    "INSERT INTO favorites (column1, column2) VALUES(100,'someText');"
    });
```

(Not taking into account that what you're trying to do actually makes sense.)

Comment: That actually worked for me. But now I have another error. 03-12 14:19:19.145: I/some(4214): stderr = Error: unable to open database "/data/data/com.android.launcher/databases/launcher.db": unable to open database file
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any conflicts in the insertion operations use `insert` with attributes and values as following:

```
Process runJob = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.launcher/databases/launcher.db \"INSERT INTO favorites (column1, column2) VALUES(100,'someText');\"");
```