# command line and adb problems

Tags: android, cmd, sqlite, adb

Hello I'm trying to execute sql query from command line using adb

```
adb.exe shell su -c "sqlite3 /data/system/users/0/accounts.db -c 'insert into accounts (name,type,password) values ('test','test','test');'"
```

and have an error:

```
sqlite3: Error: too many options: "insert into accounts (name,type,password) values (test,test,test);"
```

Can anybody help with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["sqlite3: Error: too many options: "INTO" " in android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350531/sqlite3-error-too-many-options-into-in-android-application)

Comment: @chembrad That solution does not work here.

Comment: Try without the second `-c`.

Comment: without second -c I have an error "no such column: test"